# How to create instant view in telegram using bots?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-instant-view

I am working on creating instant view for content of my channel in telegram. As I've read on the page: https://tgraph.io/How-can-I-get-IV-for-my-domain-10-22 using @bold bot we can remove long and scary created link via telegram instant view panel from a post. but because @bold is a inline bot it has limitation in lenght of post character. My main question is how @bold remove those long url and convert to IV and can I write my own bot do the same as @bold does but with my custom setting?